# Named Routes in Symfony 6 with controllers in inner directory

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing, symfony6

I moved all my controllers to `/src/Web/Controller` in my Symfony 6 project like follows

```
├── src
│   ├── ...
│   └── Web
│   |    ├── Controller
│   |    ├── ....
|   |── Kernel.php
```

my `routes.yaml` is modified accordingly

```yaml
#routes.yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../src/Web/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

Now the problem is all my routes have a name which is prefixed with `app_web`. Which due to this structure I suppose.

`$ php bin/console debug:router` command outputs following:

```
...
...
app_web_post_index    GET|HEAD        ANY      ANY    /post/             
app_web_post_create   GET|HEAD|POST   ANY      ANY    /post/create
```

Here I only want the name to be `post_index` How do I get rid of this prefix?

Comment: That seems very strange.  Can you post the annotations for one of your routes?  It's possible to specify a route prefix but it's something you have to do explicitly.  Might also try grepping for `app_web` just to see where it shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not name the routes explicitly, they are named for you.

The names are generated using the fully qualified name for the class and method for the controller (although without the last part of the namespace —`controller`—, for some reason).

If you do not want to use the auto-generated names, simply name your routes yourself:

```
#[Route('/post')]
class Post
{
    #[Route(path: '/', name: 'post_index', methods: ['HEAD', 'GET'])]
    public function index(Request $request): Response
    {
        return new Response('post index');
    }

    #[Route(path: '/create', name: 'post_create', methods: ['HEAD', 'GET', 'POST'])]
    public function create(Request $request): Response
    {
        return new Response('post create');
    }
}
```

With the built-in options [you can **add** a prefix to a group of routes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-groups-and-prefixes), but not remove it from the auto-generated name.

If this is really important for your use case to happen "automatically", I guess [you could build your own route loader](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html#creating-a-custom-loader), but I'd say it is overkill for this. Just name the routes appropriately, or live with the auto-generated name.

---

Naming the routes explicitly is generally a better idea/practice, because if you refer to the route names anywhere else you'd be guaranteed of the names remaining the same even if you chose to refactor your controllers to a different code structure.

Comment: I see, definitely I do not want to name each one of my route. Looks like I have to live with it.

Comment: It is a best practice to explicitly name your routes should you use their name somewhere in you code. ie: in twig with the `path` function

Comment: that's generally right, @Julien. Hadn't mentioned since it seemed out of scope for the question, but I've edited the answer to mention that aspect as well.

Comment: @Shobi please be aware that most of the time, naming the routes explicitly is a better idea. the cost is minimal, and you'd be potentially saving future-you some hassle. check the updated answer that mentions this fact.